# How do I restore the default folder icon?

Tags: macos, finder, folders, icon

I build web sites on a Mac and after the recent upgrade to Mavericks, the icon for all of my web template folders have changed from the standard Mac folder icon to the Parallels icon. I can change it using Get Info, but this has to be done one folder at a time and is unnecessarily tedious.

Has anyone else encountered this, and more importantly does anyone know how to reset the default to display the standard blue Mac folder icon?

Here is what it looks like right now:

[image]

Answer (score 21):

1. Get Info on the folder.
2. Click the icon on the top-left of the window.
3. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

Alternatively, `cd` into the directory and run

```
rm Icon$'\r'
```

---

To delete the icon from multiple folders at the same time, run the following command:

```
find ~/Desktop -name Icon$'\r' -delete
```

<sup>Replace `~/Desktop` with the containing folder of the folders that you wish to remove the icons from.</sup>

Comment: We worked on this answer [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11705/discussion-between-grgarside-and-fmz) if anyone wants to know the isolation process.

Comment: That find command looks dangerous, especially if there are any other files called Icon? in the Desktop or under it (IconA, IconB, Icons, etc.)

Comment: @Scott Fixed: used `$'\r'` in find command

Comment: More low-level information on the `Icon?` files is covered in [this superuser question](http://superuser.com/questions/298785/icon-file-on-os-x-desktop). -- P.S. If this isn't the proper method of connecting cross-site answers, please accept my apologies and update the answer (a cursory search turned up results about different sorts of cross-referencing).

Answer (score 2):

Go to `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/` this is where the resources are. the icon for generic folder is called "GenericFolderIcon.icns". What image is it in your system/ Is it the image of the Parallels icon? By default it should be the blue folder icon.
Source http://yukiyamashina.github.io/blog/2014/10/19/how-to-change-the-color-of-default-folder-icons-in-OS-X-Yosemite/

or you can try [liteIcon](http://www.freemacsoft.net/liteicon/)

Answer (score -1):

in the new Yosemite, sip doesn't allow you to change system files due to sip.

system integration protection (sip):

Good to stop viruses and malware, but bad for people who like to tinker. Remember to turn it back on and understand the risks of turning it off. They are important to know;

To turn off sip:

1. Restart mac
2. When restarting hold cmd+r
3. Select terminal
4. Type in "csrutil disable"
5. Click return
6. From the  menu select restart
7. To enable sip again repeat, but type in "csrutil enable" instead

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question.