# How to change the recent files smart folder icon in the dock?

Tags: macos, catalina, dock, icon

I create a recent files smart folder, place it in the dock. I right click and choose display as folder. I get the following icon:

[image: Picture]

Is there a way to change this icon?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100332/how-can-i-change-a-smart-folders-icon-without-changing-the-default-icon?rq=1 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111955/how-do-i-restore-the-default-folder-icon?rq=1

Comment: I don't think these answer the question. Because when you normally place folders on the dock, you can't see their contents using the fan view or grid view. I'd like to specifically replace this file drawer icon with something else.

Comment: They do. You have to go to `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/` and replace the icon file with another, of the same name. The first link in the first comment tells me this. so does second link. I votes to close as 3rd as that was the easy GUI way.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't edit system files. Do I need to use Terminal?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/376297/313842 follow this answer, give it a full read first.

Answer (score -2):

You can easily change any icon folder from any picture you want (copy the picture you want -> get info of the folder -> click the actual picture folder -> paste the new picture).

From [Apple support](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-custom-icons-files-folders-mac-mchlp2313/mac) to change picture of folder :

**Create custom icons for files or folders on Mac**

You can create a custom icon for any file or folder using your own pictures, icons downloaded from the web, or the icon from another file or folder.

**Use your own picture or a picture from the web**

1. On your Mac, copy the picture you want to use to the Clipboard.

   One way to do this is to open the picture in the Preview app , choose Edit > Select All, then choose Edit > Copy.
2. Select the file or folder whose icon you want to replace, then choose File > Get Info.
3. At the top of the Info window, click the picture of the icon, then choose Edit > Paste.

Comment: Copying answers is inferior to closing questions as dupes.

Comment: And this stopped working with mavericks, as per comments under https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/100372/313842. Catalina is even more restrictive.

Comment: Apple claims that you still can do it on Catalina

Comment: How can I select the "recents" folder as you say in step 2 ? Can you share the screenshot of its get info window ?

Comment: The dock only works as a shortcut, you have to select your "recents" folder where it as been created.

Comment: That's the issue: Recents is not a common folder like Downloads, or Desktop, or any custom one. See the difference between, say desktop, and recents: https://imgur.com/a/PtmT89e. If it were so easy, https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/376297/313842 this wouldn't be necessary. Also, as https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100332/ this answer says, the recents folder's icon sits in `/System/`.